# Simplest nodejs echo server

Tags: node.js, stream, pipe

I am getting acquainted with streams in nodejs and I have a question:

I have what I think is the simplest possible nodejs "echo server" ie a server that simple pipes back to the response stream whatever it receives via the request stream. 
It works but with a caveat. The client only receives the data back after it closes the submitting stream.
Here is the server code:

```
var http = require('http')
var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  req.pipe(res);
});
server.listen(8000);
```

And here is how I test it:

Doing the following works just fine

```
term1> node server.js&

term2> echo 'hello world!'|curl --no-buffer --data-binary  @-  'http://localhost:8000'
hello world!
```

However, it only works because echo closes its output file descriptor after being done, ie., the server will not write anything until after its client is done sending stuff:

```
term2>
term2> yes|curl --no-buffer --data-binary  @-  'http://localhost:8000'
```

(here this line gets stuck for ever)

I would expect that `yes` will fill stream buffers pretty fast so I would start seeing y's coming back pretty fast. Unfortunately they never do.

Is this expected? How should I use the streams/pipes so as they have the desired effect?
By the way I don't care whether the output would come back in chunks... I understand that that would be results of streams (or the underlying file i/o) doing their buffering magic.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, 
I think I figured out what I was doing wrong.
The `server.js` was working fine... it was `curl` that was breaking the pipeline.
Apparently, the `@-` option treats stdin like a file ,ie reads its full content and then submits it. I couldn't find how to make `curl` pipe the contents as they are being read. I think its not feasible because `curl` wants to treat the contents of the file as a normal HTTP post form value..

Anyway, I modified the example above using a simple nodejs client that was doing what I wanted:

```
term2> cat client.js
var http = require('http');
var req = http.request('http://localhost:8000', function(res) {
  res.pipe(process.stdout);
});
process.stdin.pipe(req);

term2> yes|node client.js
y
y
...
```

nodejs streams and pipes rock!!

Comment: What does the pipe do exactly? Do you always call it on the request and pass it the response of the http.createServer function?