# Using pipe() in Node.js net

Tags: javascript, node.js, tcp

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around the `pipe` function shown in several Node.js examples for the [net](http://nodejs.org/api/net.html) module.

```
var net = require('net');

var server = net.createServer(function (socket) {
  socket.write('Echo server\r\n');
  socket.pipe(socket);
});
```

Can anyone offer an explanation on how this works and why it's required?

Answer (score 115, accepted):

The `pipe()` function reads data from a readable stream as it becomes available and writes it to a destination writable stream.

The example in the documentation is an echo server, which is a server that sends what it receives. The `socket` object implements both the readable and writable stream interface, so it is therefore writing any data it receives back to the socket.

This is the equivalent of using the `pipe()` method using event listeners:

```
var net = require('net');
net.createServer(function (socket) {
  socket.write('Echo server\r\n');
  socket.on('data', function(chunk) {
    socket.write(chunk);
  });
  socket.on('end', socket.end);
});
```

Comment: Could you link to the documentation of pipe(net.Soctket). Or there is no any ?

Comment: It's located [here](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pipe_destination_options). Then, if you take a look [here](http://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_class_net_socket), it's stated that `net.Socket` instances implement a duplex stream.

Comment: but what "implement ad duplex stream interface" mean ? Does it mean that it inherits from it? Stream is in net.Socket prototype ?  Why is it called "interface" when interface to me is just "document" that specify what methods could you find in some object..

Comment: Yes, it means it inherits from `stream.Duplex`, which inherits both `stream.Readable` and `stream.Writable`. In this context, "interface" isn't strictly the OOP definition of interface, it can just be a contact point between applications.

Comment: What do you mean by "contact point between applications" ?   And why they use such a term that could be misleading. And they won't say how it's implemented (is this object is in prototype chain, or is it a mixin)

Comment: I mean that an alternate definition for "interface" is the point where two systems interact - I don't really have a better way to explain. As for the implementation of the streams, you can take a look at the source, such as places like [here](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/net.js#L289). You can see that stream prototypes are being called directly from the socket's prototype methods.

Comment: how to wait for pipe to complete the operation like if i have something like this `myfun().pipe(fs.createWriteStream(file_path));`  in such case how can i wait of pipe to complete because if directly go below i may get error as writestream may have not finished writing to file

Answer (score 6):

`pipe()` reads from a readable stream and writes to a writeable stream, much like a Unix pipe.  It does all "reasonable" things along the way with errors, end of files, if one side falls behind etc.  Your particular example is slightly confusing because the `socket` is both readable and writeable.

An easier to understand example is [in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17190733/simplest-nodejs-echo-server) where you read from an http request and write to an http response.

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 sockets per Server-Client Connection (2 endpoints). Socket binds `IP Address:Port Number`. The client gets assigned random port numbers, while the server has dedicated port number. This is the basic explanation of how socket works.

Piping is reserved for redirecting a readable stream to a writable stream.

What `socket.pipe(socket)` does? 
It redirects all the data from the readable stream (server) to the writable stream (client). We can tweak this by adding event listeners as @hexacyanide has pointed out.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following request handler

```
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res){
     console.log('Request for ' + req.url + ' by method ' + req.method);
    if(req.method == 'GET'){
        var fileurl;
        if(req.url == '/')fileurl = '/index.html';
        else {
            fileurl = req.url;
        }
    }
    var filePath = path.resolve('./public'+fileurl);
    var fileExt = path.extname(filePath);
    if(fileExt == '.html'){
          fs.exists(filePath, function(exists){
        if(!exists){
          res.writeHead(404, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
          res.end('<h1>Error 404' + filePath + 'not found </h1>');
          //the end() method sends content of the response to the client
          //and signals to the server that the response has been sent
          //completely
          return;
        }
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':'text/html'});
        fs.createReadStream(filePath).pipe(res);
      })
    }
}
```

The `fs.createReadStream` method reads the file in the given file path (`public/index.html`) and `pipe()` writes it to the response (`res`) for client's view.