# MaxListenersExceededWarning with one client

Tags: node.js, sockets, tcp

I'm logging a GPS device with node.js and I'm having a weird behavior.

My server code is very simple

```js
var net = require('net');

var server = net.createServer(function(socket) {
    var imei;

    console.log("Socket: " + socket.remoteAddress + ":" + socket.remotePort);

    socket.on("data", function(data){
        var txt = data.toString("utf-8");

        console.log(txt);

        if(!imei){
            imei = parseInt(txt.split("imei:")[1]);
        }

        // login device
        if(txt.startsWith("##") && txt.endsWith(",A;")){
            socket.write('LOAD');
        // heartbeat
        }else if(parseInt(txt) == imei){
            socket.write(`ON`);
        }
        socket.pipe(socket);
    });
    socket.on("end", function () {
        console.log("out!")
    });
});

server.listen(8888);
```

After log the GPS device, it sends a heartbeat every one minute, I'm working only with one device, so it's only one client.

The server output looks like this:

```
Socket: ::ffff:191.000.000.000:9292 // new client
##,imei:000000000000000,A; // login
000000000000000; // heartbeat 
000000000000000;
000000000000000;
000000000000000;
000000000000000;
000000000000000;
000000000000000;
000000000000000;
(node:12684) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 end listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
```

As you can see, after some messages it shows `MaxListenersExceededWarning`, but I'm confuse, if there only one client connected why I'm seeing this message?
there is something wrong with the code?
How could I solve this problem?

***EDIT:***

after adding the `--trace-warnings` flag

I'm seeing this output:

```
(node:8592) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 end listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
    at _addListener (events.js:280:19)
    at Socket.addListener (events.js:297:10)
    at Socket.Readable.on (_stream_readable.js:772:35)
    at Socket.once (events.js:341:8)
    at Socket.Readable.pipe (_stream_readable.js:580:9)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (server.js:30:16)
    at emitOne (events.js:121:20)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:263:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:250:11)
```

Line 30 of the server code is: `socket.pipe(socket);`

Comment: Could you add the output when running `node --trace-warnings [nameOfYourFile].js`

Comment: Adding `--trace-warnings` shows the same output: `(node:7120) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 end listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit`

Comment: Ok I was adding `--trace-warnings` at the end that's why it doesn't work. I've edited the post with the new information

Comment: I would try something like 
`require('events').EventEmitter.prototype._maxListeners = 15;` in the server code

Comment: I solved it removing `pipe` from the code. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Glad you figured it out ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is I was using `socket.pipe(socket);` to send data back to the device, but `pipe` shouldn't be used in this case because it sends all the socket object, I assume in each message the socket was nesting its own values, and it really was a memory leak.

After removing the `pipe` line code, the warning was gone

More information about pipe: [Using pipe() in Node.js net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20085513/using-pipe-in-node-js-net/20085692)