# Downloading an API file to Firebase Cloud Storage?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage, text-to-speech, ibm-watson

How do I save an audio file (about 10K) from IBM Watson Text-to-speech to Firebase Cloud Storage? Here's my code, copied from the IBM Watson [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/text-to-speech/api/v1/node.html?node#synthesize):

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

var TextToSpeechV1 = require('watson-developer-cloud/text-to-speech/v1');
var fs = require('fs');    

exports.TextToSpeech = functions.firestore.document('Test_Value').onUpdate((change, context) => {

  var textToSpeech = new TextToSpeechV1({
    username: 'groucho',
    password: 'swordfish',
    url: 'https://stream.watsonplatform.net/text-to-speech/api'
  });

  var synthesizeParams = {
    text: 'Hello world',
    accept: 'audio/wav',
    voice: 'en-US_AllisonVoice'
  };

  textToSpeech.synthesize(synthesizeParams).on('error', function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  }).pipe(fs.createWriteStream('hello_world.wav')); // what goes here?

  const file = ?????
  file.download()
  .then(function(data) {
    console.log("File downloaded."
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
  });
});
```

The missing code is between

```
}).pipe(fs.createWriteStream('hello_world.wav'));
```

and

```
file.download()
```

Somehow I have to convert the file provided by IBM Watson into a file that Firebase Cloud Storage recognizes. Is `fs` not allowed in Google Cloud Functions?

Also, shouldn't line 6 be

```
var fs = require('fs-js');
```

not

```
var fs = require('fs');
```

According to [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs) the `fs` package is deprecated.

Is `pipe` allowed in Google Cloud Functions? If so, what do I pipe the file to? I need something that looks like this:

```
}).pipe(file);
file.download()
```

Comment: I can help but I have a question first - what type of variable do you need `file` to be? A `Buffer`? I mostly want to know, where is that `download()` function coming from - or is that pseudocode?

Comment: You need to return a promise from your function that resolves when all the work is complete.  `pipe` is probably an async function, which means you need to start thinking more carefully about how you want to do async programming in your function.

Comment: Doug, IBM Watson textToSpeech.synthesize returns a callback, not a promise. I'll look into Google text-to-speech, if that returns a promise will it be easier to code?

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20085513/using-pipe-in-node-js-net, "The pipe() function [in Node] reads data from a readable stream as it becomes available and writes it to a destination writable stream." I want to write to a file. I'll look into whether there's a pipe-to-file Node command.

Comment: Another answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20085513/using-pipe-in-node-js-net says that "pipe() reads from a readable stream and writes to a writeable stream, much like a Unix pipe. It does all "reasonable" things along the way with errors, end of files, if one side falls behind etc." That sounds like async.

Comment: dpopp07, the documentation for file.download() is at https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/2.0.x/File#download download() goes to Firebase Cloud Storage. The files are coming from IBM Watson Text-to-Speech. These are audio files, .ogg or .mp3, typically 12K. The files should be ready to download, but Doug pointed out that there may be async issues, i.e., I need to think about finishing receiving the file from IBM Watson before sending the file to download().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks dpopp07, I got it!

```
exports.TextToSpeech = functions.firestore.document('Test_Word').onUpdate((change, context) => {

if (change.after.data().word != undefined) {
    myWord = change.after.data().word;
    myWordFileType = myWord + '.ogg';

  var synthesizeParams = {
        text: myWord,
        accept: 'audio/ogg',
        voice: 'en-US_AllisonVoice'
      };

      const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
      const storage = new Storage();
      const bucket = storage.bucket('myapp.appspot.com');
      const file = bucket.file('Test_Folder' + myWordFileType);

      var TextToSpeechV1 = require('watson-developer-cloud/text-to-speech/v1');

      var textToSpeech = new TextToSpeechV1({
        username: 'groucho',
        password: 'swordfish',
        url: 'https://stream.watsonplatform.net/text-to-speech/api'
      });

      textToSpeech.synthesize(synthesizeParams).on('error', function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      }).pipe(file.createWriteStream({contentType: 'auto'}))
      .on('error', function(err) {})
      .on('finish', function() {
        console.log("Complete.");
      });
      }
      return 0;
    });
```

The function triggers when a new word is written to a Firestore location, then extracts the word and calls it `myWord`. Adding .ogg makes `myWordFileType`. The functions sends an HTTP request to IBM Watson Text-to-speech, which returns a callback, not a promise, so the code is a bit ugly. The crux is where the HTTP response goes through Node command `pipe` to the send the file to the Google Cloud Storage command [file.createWriteStream](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/2.0.x/File#createWriteStream). The `contentType` must be set to get a readable file, but `auto` makes this easy. The file is then written to the bucket, which is set to my Firebase Cloud Storage folder `Test_Folder` and the filename is `myWordFileType`.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, reviewing the documentation for `file.download()`, I think you can make this work with little change to your code. `file` needs to be type `File` from the Google Storage library (you'll need to install [this library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/storage)). This type has a method called [`createWriteStream`](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/2.0.x/File#createWriteStream) that you can stream the results of `synthesize` to. I didn't test this but I believe it should be correct or should at least point you in the right direction:

```
// looks like you'll need to require this package also
const { Storage } = require('@google-cloud/storage');

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

var TextToSpeechV1 = require('watson-developer-cloud/text-to-speech/v1');
var fs = require('fs');    

const storage = new Storage();
const myBucket = storage.bucket('my-bucket');

exports.TextToSpeech = functions.firestore.document('Test_Value').onUpdate((change, context) => {

  var textToSpeech = new TextToSpeechV1({
    username: 'groucho',
    password: 'swordfish',
    url: 'https://stream.watsonplatform.net/text-to-speech/api'
  });

  var synthesizeParams = {
    text: 'Hello world',
    accept: 'audio/wav',
    voice: 'en-US_AllisonVoice'
  };

  const file = myBucket.file('my-file'); // name your file something here

  textToSpeech
    .synthesize(synthesizeParams)
    .on('error', function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    })
    .pipe(file.createWriteStream()) // the File object has a `createWriteStream` method for writing streams to it
    .on('error', function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    })
    .on('finish', function() {
      // The file upload is complete.
      file.download()
        .then(function(data) {
          console.log("File downloaded.");
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error(error);
        });
    });
});
```

For the record:

- `pipe()` should be allowed in Google Cloud Functions and it *is* async. This is why you need to listen for the `finish` event before downloading the file
- `fs` is only deprecated on public NPM but that is not the package you were importing, the `fs` (file system) module is one of [Node's core built-in packages](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v8.x/api/fs.html). That said, it looks like you might not need it in your code at all

Comment: Thanks, I was just reading the documentation and saw file.createWriteStream. Running your code I get an error message "file is not defined" at the file.createWriteStream line. The documentation includes "const file = myBucket.file('my-file');". I'll keep working at it.

Comment: Thanks again, I've written up the working code as an answer and upvoted your answer.